# jQuery only works on first CodeIgniter view, not the second, why?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two CodeIgniter views in my application, both of which have a text field. My problem is, my jQuery code only works on the first CodeIgniter view when my application loads. When my app displays the second view, my jQuery code does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-field").attr("value","I'm looking for...");
    var text = "I'm looking for...";
    $(".input-field").focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if($(this).attr("value") == text) $(this).attr("value", "");
    });
    $(".input-field").blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        if($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", text);
    });
});
```

Here are my script tags located in the head section of both CodeIgniter Views. Also, both views have the same class name `input-field`. Why does my jQuery not work on the second view?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: how is the second view displayed? ajax?

Comment: The second view is displayed after the user submits the form on the first view. The controller calls the second view like this: `$this->view('my_view',$data);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation as it seems you are dealing with dynamic elements

The events are changed to [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusin) and [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusout) because by definition focus and blur does not bubble

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input-field").attr("value", "I'm looking for...");

    var text = "I'm looking for...";

    $(document).on('focusin', ".input-field", function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if ($(this).attr("value") == text) $(this).attr("value", "");
    });
    $(document).on('focusout', ".input-field", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", text);
    });
});
```